How do I get the keywords of a specific layer?
I need to get the keywords of a specific layer from the geoserver. I have the name of the word in the format workspace:name. I would like to get keywords for this particular layer. I know that it is possible to send a wms/GetCapabilities request and get layers of a certain namespace. But is it possible to limit yourself even more and get a certain layer and necessarily along with keywords?
